# Dependencies not getting updated in TFS Build Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cab

I have created a Smart Device CAB Deployment Project and contains dependencies eg: Test.dll.
Where Test is a seperate class library. I have created a build definition for this solution(contains Test Proj + CAB deployment Proj). When i trigger queue new build for this definition Test.dll is not getting updated in CAB deployment project in Build Agent folder of TFS Server.

PLease let me know how can i reload this dependencies on checking in / queuing new build.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check your Workspace option on Process tab. It should be All or Outputs if you wish to have always fresh version. None option is for incremental builds. If your project is really small "All" is the best option for you.

- All - erase entire workspace and download and build everything again
- Outputs - like All but only output bin folders are erased and new
  version is downloaded (get latest version) from source control.
  (incremental get) (like Rebuild (cleen + build) in your solution)
- None - sources are build incrementally. Like Get latest version +
  Build command in VS

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried with Outputs but still no luck. I Cannot keep "All" since it deletes entire workspace which might affect other projects

Comment: You should have all your project references included in the build definition workspace like you have it in your local workspace.

Comment: I have included the references in build definition workspace but still the references not getting updated in workspace but these are getting refreshed in my local folder.

Comment: They are not included because you have Worskpace set to Outputs. Set it to All, build and then back to the Outputs.